# render Object of json to dataTable in play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, datatable

I am getting json in following format :

```
0 Object { email="admin@gmail.com",name="Admin"}
1 Object { email="admin@gmail.com",name="Admin"}
```

I want to render it on [dataTable](https://datatables.net/) .
I am using Play framework and scala.

Comment: What version of Play are you working with? Can you go into more detail on how your getting that JSON? Is a Play controller returning that data or are you requesting that data with Play?

Comment: If you already have the endpoint delivering the JSON, then you probably just need to learn [how to handle data using DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/data/) and how to use [ajax to get remote data](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax).

Comment: i am using play 2.5 .  Following code is used to generate json : ' clientService.getAll.map {
        clients => implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Client]
          Ok(Json.toJson(clients))} '

Comment: i am using following code to render data on dataTable : 'var ajaxCallBack = {
                        cache : false,
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('#example').DataTable( {
                                data: data
                            } );
                        }, '  but itsnot working